# I want to develop a web app in a scripting language without mutable state

Tags: web-apps, web-development, language, scripting, haskell

I like Django and Rails because changes to my backend can load very fast (compared to a Java based web framework) and I like Haskell because of the absence of mutable state. I would like a web framework that can load changes as fast as Django or Rails but that doesn't have mutable state.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. Haskell is purely functional and hence avoids certain kind of state. But if your entire website is stateless, then what changes would you be loading? What would be changing? Are you just trying to ask for a web framework that's usable with Haskell?

Comment: I'm asking for a web framework written in a language that is not compiled and that is purely functional like Haskell.

Comment: How about: https://wiki.haskell.org/Web/Frameworks